# I am looking for a responsive slider that can take text instead of images

Tags: 7, javascript

Do you know of a responsive slider that can take text instead of images?

I have been using Nivo Slider and have had great experiences with its responsive design. I am using one on the front page. I wanted another, so I used Views Nivo Slider. My client decided to have another with text instead of pictures, but Views Nivo Slider didn't seem to want to do this. I don't think I can hack the Nivo Slider code because it would effect my other sliders on my webpage.

Here are some pictures. With images, the slider behaves normally.
[image]

When I add the body content and change the slider to show the body as so,

[image]

I get this:

[image]

Nothing shows up.

The same thing happens if I try to put the body into the title instead of the image.

Comment: can you provide screenshots or examples of the errors you are encountering?

Comment: It looks like a CSS issue with word length maybe, by which I mean images can resize easily -- I doubt they mean it to be used with solely text. Eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733527/nivo-slider-add-text-to-the-slider

Comment: When I look at my page, there is only HTML tags within the slider tags. This question was mainly to see if there was a module that did this without changing code, but I am willing to try to get it to work. I am just worried that my changes will effect the other sliders on my page. Also, I changed the CSS code and it didn't do anything.

Comment: With your comments, I decided to try to put an image and the body into the title. This showed the text. I think I will put a blank image and have the text show up that way. Thank You! If you put an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [jCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) uses the [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) jQuery plugin which can do text too

Answer (score 1):

There is a smaller group out there Theme Boutique who built a really remarkable slideshow tool called the Revolution Slider.  It's currently out ther and available on their Dawn Responsive theme (I have used their BigWig theme in the past with the same slideshow).  It worked really well and didn't require alot of the gymnastics that I've seen with other solutions.

Here's a demo video of it in action.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZL2renvh5o